# How to wrap object across curve area?

Tags: uv, shrinkwrap

I have an eyebrow that I want to wrap across a cylinder shape face. I don't know how to wrap it where it would bend perfectly around the cylinder.

I tried using shrinkwrap modifier but that deforms the shape or doesn't maintain the correct thickness.

Here is the current eyebrow without any modifiers.

[image]

If I use outside surface it makes it curve yet its super thin and not touching properly.

[image]

Is there an easy way to get this to wrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a lattice, scale it in *Object* mode to make it a bit bigger than your eyebrow, in the *Object Data* panel set its resolution to someting like 5/1/5 so that its a flat grid. Give a *Shrinkwrap* modifier to this lattice with the cylinder as *Target*, put the lattice a bit into the cylinder:

[image]

Give your eyebrow a *Lattice* modifier with the lattice as *Object*, the eyebrow will stick to the cylinder with the correct deformation:

[image]

Comment: the concept is there, but when I set the eyebrows to become a child of my body(cylinder) they move inwards whenever I move the body. Note I added a mirror modifier to make the second eyebrow, but behaves strange when I try to parent it and move the whole body around

Comment: actually when I move the entire cylinder, the lattice moves across the x axis and isn't staying in the single position that I set it at

Comment: so I guess you need to parent the lattice as well, but why don't you apply the modifiers instead?

Comment: right I forgot to parent the lattice, that was my issue!