# How to Make Silver Color without HDRI Image?

Tags: shaders, color, hdri

So I tried to follow the tutorials on YT for silver, but every single one of them says to add an HDRI image to your project.

When I do that it completely brightens my entire animation and the only thing I want to have affected my the hdri image is the one object cylinder that I want to turn silver

Is there an easier way to make a cylinder a shiny silver without affecting my entire world in my project?

[image]

So with an HDRI image it lightens all my other objects and even with it my cylinder is still just a dull gray color without any shiny silver effect.

Comment: I think you should accpet some answers in your question list first,ie:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255802/how-to-wrap-object-across-curve-area, for this question, change the metal to 1,roughness to 0, in your principle BSDF, and turn your render from EE to Cycle.

Comment: @natureK whenever I switch to cycles my entire app lags like crazy

Comment: render of course take much time, try to lower your sampling in the render settings.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In the example above Suzanne is standing in for your cylinder, and a Glossy BSDF node is standing in for whatever your tutorial recommends.  Please note the Texture Coordinate node output used is Reflection.  The colors in the Color Ramp should be picked from your scene, the Factor of the Mix RGB node should be used to mix the colors with gray (for the silvery color).  I've left the Scale of the Voronoi node low to make the effect obvious, the effect you want may need it higher.  If you animate the scene you'll see the effect move as if it were reflected:

[image]

Alternately (below), instead of the Voronoi / Color Ramp nodes, you can use an HDRI **in an Image Texture node of your material** (NOT in World).  Please note the Texture Coordinate node output used is still Reflection, and the HDRI is **not** affecting the lighting:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you rendering it in cycles or can this be possible in evee mode? I tried cycles and it's literally impossible for me to use for my animation without waiting 100x longer

Comment: This is in EEVEE (as I made sure was clear in the screenshots, pink arrow pointing at "EEVEE" in the Render Properties and at Rendered Viewport Shading).  You shouldn't be experiencing any unusual delays during animation with this.  I'd recommend doing a simple animation (in EEVEE, it's already set to that) in the blend I included, and then try this method in your project.  If you're getting delays doing this in your project but not in my example file then this isn't what's causing your delays.

Comment: Hey @makerbaker did this answer your question?  If so, I'd appreciate a checkmark.  If not, why not?  Didn't work, or not the results you were going for, or . . . ?

Comment: Hey @makerbaker I see you've started accepting answers, nice!  Did my response answer your question?  I'd appreciate a checkmark if it did, otherwise it'd be helpful to know why it doesn't.